# Are React Functional Components Regular Functions or Constructor Functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

In olden times (in other words, a few years ago) React Components were classes with a `render` method.

```
class MyComponents extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>...</div>
    }
}
```

In more recent times, React's introduced functional components.

```
function MyComponent() {
    return <div>...</div>
}
```

Either of the above would let you use your component in another bit of JSX -- something like this

```
<Navigation>
    <MyComponent/>
</Navigation>
```

I'd like to know if, behind the scenes, React is using these functional component functions as object constructors or is it just calling the component function as a regular function.

That is -- you can call a javascript function

```
function someFunction() {
    //...
}

const result = someFunction()
```

Or, you can use a javascript function to create a new object

```
function SomeFunction() {
    //...
}

const object = new SomeFunction()
```

In plain javascript the *convention* is usually that a function that's `Capitalized` is a constructor function, and function that's not is a regular function.  However, a lot of the shallow blog articles I read on components indicate (but never state outright) that these component functions are used as regular functions and *not* as object constructors.

Does anyone here know whether functional components are object constructors, regular functions, or if React's doing some third weird thing behind the scenes.  Bonus points if you can point out the particular bit(s) of React's internal code that's doing this.

Comment: Interesting question.  I haven't found the right line just yet but [createElement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9198a5cec0936a21a5ba194a22fcbac03eba5d1d/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L348) calls [ReactElement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9198a5cec0936a21a5ba194a22fcbac03eba5d1d/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L146) which has a comment *"Factory method to create a new React element. This no longer adheres to the class pattern, so do not use new to call it. Also, instanceof check will not work."*

Comment: React does not call function components as a constructor. You can tell this because arrow functions are perfectly legal as function components, but they aren't legal as constructors.

Comment: Thank you @NicholasTower -- when you say "arrow functions are perfectly legal as function components" -- is that documented anywhere, or is it just a common practice (I'm not doubting you're correct, I'm just newish to this part of React and trying to learn as much as I can)

Comment: Thank you @LindaPaiste - those are useful code point to start exploring from.  "This no longer adheres to the class pattern, so do not use new to call it." is compelling, if circumstantial evidence.

Comment: @AlanStorm yeah it doesn't directly answer your question but it proves that React uses uppercase names for things which aren't classes and aren't `new`-able.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I've tracked this one down conclusively.  Functional Components are *not* invoked as constructor-functions -- they're just called as regular function.

First -- if I add some debugging to a component

```
    function MyComponent() {
        /* ... */
        console.log(this)
        /* ... */
    }
```

the value of `this` is undefined.  That's consistent with code calling `MyComponent`  as a function.  If code invoked `new MyComponent`, `this` would be an instance of a `MyComponent` object.

Second, if I'm reading the source right, it looks like [this conditional](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f227e7f26b81cb1eba0c837ab2acd7fa7f91404f/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactPartialRenderer.js#L464) is one place where React has branching logic for dealing with class-based vs. function-based components.

A class based component [gets the `new` treatment](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f227e7f26b81cb1eba0c837ab2acd7fa7f91404f/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactPartialRenderer.js#L465), but [a function based component](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f227e7f26b81cb1eba0c837ab2acd7fa7f91404f/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactPartialRenderer.js#L534) does not.

```
    if (isClass) {
      inst = new Component(element.props, publicContext, updater);
      /*...*/
    } else {
      /* ... */
      inst = Component(element.props, publicContext, updater);
      /* ... */
    }
```